# Self solution based on suggestion from comments

Tags: discussion

I know I can post a solution against my own question if there is no satisfactory reply and I solve it myself. But the situation here is a little different. I made a question which finally got no reply, but one user has provided some of his ideas with the possibilities to solve the issue through comments and using one of his 'idea' I've finally solved the issue myself.

Here, the credit is not mine as I was lost with the problem and might not solve it if someone's idea was not there. But the idea came with a few words which may be difficult to handle other members having the same issue.

So, my question appears here: what should I do? Shall I post my detailed coded solution how I have solved for other users' future reference as the credit is not mine, at least not completely. Also, if I post it shall I mark it as solution (green tick)? Though I don't know I can do that with my own answer or not but I preferred asking on the first hand to experienced members as I think marking like that has an impact to the reputation credential ...

I've searched for similar question but couldn't find what I'm exactly asking. Sorry if I've missed any ...

Comment: I can't tell you how much I love it when people make some effort to try to learn how a community works and what is expected. Kudos for asking.

Comment: Yes, please answer and accept. Personally, if I comment with hints instead of writing a full answer due to lack of time or interest, I appreciate the original poster completing the work and marking the question as resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Should I post and answer

Ultimately the most important thing is that an answer is posted. Comments are temporary post it notes and are not well suited to full answers. You can suggest the commenters do so, but assuming they do not then posting your own answer is a good idea.

## Should I accept credit

This is ultimately up to you, if you don't want to gain reputation from it you can mark it as [Community Wiki](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11740/what-are-community-wiki-posts) but it sounds like you added significant novel material so I wouldn't begrudge you your reputation from it. However, you may wish to reference the comment within your answer.

The green tick mark isn't actually that important, if you don't get any other answers I might tick your own answer but don't lose sleep over it.

Comment: Right, I preferred myself posting my solution ignoring all other mentioned aspects just for a single reason: Many members may not like to storm-head for a lengthy coding against my question but it will drive the interest of greater amount of people to further improve my final solution if they get a readymade solution to play with. I just wanted to make sure what I'm doing is right. Thanks for your guidance, Richard.